# Svelte Jest test case making document.getElementId as null

Tags: javascript, jestjs, svelte, svelte-3

I am trying to write the unit test case for my svelte component using jest-transform-svelte library. Following is the component:

XYZ.svelte

```
<script>
  function submit() {
    var name = document.getElementById("name").value; // Here document.getElementById("name") is coming as null when run from unit test case.
    dispatch("abc", {
      text: name
    });
  }
</script>
<input id="name" value="" type="text" label="Name" />
<button label="Submit" variant="primary" on:click={submit} />
```

XYZ.test.js

```
import XYZ from "XYZ.svelte";

describe("XYZ Component", () => {
  it('dispatches abc event on submit', (next) => {

    const target = document.createElement('div');
    const xyz = new XYZ({ target: target });

    setTimeout(() => {
      const button = target.querySelector("button");
      button.click();

      xyz.$on('abc', event => {
        next();
      });
    }, 10);
  });
});
```

When button.click on the test case happens, the call is triggering the submit function in XYZ.svelte but,

> document.getElementById("name")

is coming as null because of which getting null pointer exception error.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In Svelte you can eschew `document.getElementById` by binding the element's reference to a variable. Try changing your component as follows:

```
<script>
  import { createEventDispatcher } from 'svelte';

  const dispatch = createEventDispatcher();
  let name = null;

  function submit () {
    dispatch("abc", {
      text: name
    });
  }
</script>
<input bind:value={name} type="text" label="Name" />
<button label="Submit" variant="primary" on:click={submit} />
```

Comment: Thanks for providing the answer. But is there any way I can use document.getElementById in here? Why it is not working? Any idea about it?

Comment: You can use document.getElementById, since Svelte just produces regular DOM nodes. What you need to be aware of is *when* you are calling it. It's important to ensure that the nodes have been written to the DOM. You could perform some checks before you try, but the best way is to not use it - it's the same with any dynamic, javascript added DOM elements. If the node doesn't exist in the DOM when you try to select it, the selection will fail.